# Shiny UI Widgets

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

Yesterday, I ran my code and it was working fine. Today Im getting an error "Error in df$location : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" in my UI section

```
pickerInput(
  inputId = "pick",
  label = "Location Dropdown (move above marker to 1 to see everything)", 
  choices = c("NA",df$location)
),
```

Yesterday the dropdown was working fine with the df$location. Any tips/help?

Comment: are you sure df is still existing in your current environment? What happens if your use `iris$Species` instead of `df$location`?

Comment: Thank you!! I completely forgot to put df in my environment! Rookie mistake!

Answer (score 0):

Was "df" in your local environment, but not in the Shiny app? You'll need to make sure that app.R (or server.R) loads df or it'll only work in an environment where df is loaded. Easiest way to do this would be saveRDS(df, "df.rds") while building the package, then loadRDS("df.rds") early in the app.R script.